# Changing the Title View of a UINavigationController UIViewController in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Is it possible to change the title view (i.e. add a `UISegmentedControl`) for a `UIViewController` contained within a `UINavigationController` from within Interface Builder? I am currently doing this work from within code with:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.filterSegmentedControl;
}
```

However, I'd prefer to set everyone up in IB. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using IB to add a UISegmentedControl to a NavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150831/using-ib-to-add-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-a-navigationbar)

Comment: Yikes. This looks like an exact duplicate! Sorry didn't catch it.