# Change the color & background of title in iPhone view

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have a tab bar controller as a root controller. In its first tab I have a navigation controller containing an ungrouped table view

Screenshot is at - http://sankalplabs.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/screen-shot-2011-04-05-at-11-17-10-am.png

(Since I am new to this forum, its not allowing me to upload the image)

Now i want to change the color & background of the title "Smart Analytics". I tried using a label & placing it on the title. But it has not worked. What is the way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: Tried this. But the title color does not change :-(

Comment: This worked. Actually my class files were not loading. so I just deleted the app from the simulator & loaded again

Answer (score 0):

Try with `titleView` property of `UINavigationItem`

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *titleView
```

Can be accessed like below In `UIViewController` inherited class.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = myOwnLabel;
```

Related SO post

[Changing the Title View of a UINavigationController UIViewController in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881378/changing-the-title-view-of-a-uinavigationcontroller-uiviewcontroller-in-interface)

Comment: in the init function of your UIViewController inherited class ,

Comment: @user692275 : Could you post related Code ?

Comment: I have written this code in viewDidload() function of the UINavigationController as below                                    

 
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44);
 UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
 label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
 label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
 label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
 label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
 label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Smart Analytics", @"");
 self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
}

Comment: your code look me fine,As i mentioned above , use you code in the class which is inherited from UIViewController NOT UINavigationController,

Comment: @jhaliya, how do we change the color of the title but?

Answer (score 0):

```
use this

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```